# display the price in the text field when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

i want to display the price in a text field when the button is clicked, so basically i have tried with an alert and it works but instead of the alert i want to put the price in the text field when the button is clicked

Comment: Provide complete code.

Comment: This is not a complete question and should be closed. Please read the SO FAQ and Asking your first question guide before posting questions on the site. We aren't here to write code for you, we're here to help you solve a specific problem

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1):

Add id to html

```
 <input id="totalPrice" type="text" name="totalprice" readonly="readonly" >
```

Update value of input rather than alert

```
function checkPrice(){

var radios=document.getElementsByName('place');
var people= document.getElementById('noofpersons').value;

for(var i=0, length=radios.length; i<length; i++) {
if(document.form.place.value=="Maldives"){
document.getElementById('totalPrice').value = "£" + 1300*people;
break;
}
if(document.form.place.value=="Madagascar"){
document.getElementById('totalPrice').value = "£" + 899*people;
break;

if(document.form.place.value=="Hawaii"){
document.getElementById('totalPrice').value = "£" + 1100*people;
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put an Id to the textbox and use the code below:

```
// Let say the id is #price
var totalPrice = "Put the price here";
document.getElementById('price').value = totalPrice;
```

Also instead of using if, use switch statement. Because from the code, `document.form.place.value` will be able to have only 1 value.

```
switch(document.form.place.value)
{
    case "Maldives":
        document.getElementById('price').value = "£" + (1300 * people);
        break;
    case "Madagascar":
        // ...
    case "Hawaii"        
        // ...
    case default:
        break;    
}
```